# How to give dot in X axis and Y axis in line chart?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

I am implementing [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in my project to show line chart. I want to add dot in x axis and y axis as shown in the image below. Here is the image :

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
    let yAxis = lineChart.leftAxis
    yAxis.labelFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    yAxis.setLabelCount(5, force: false)
    yAxis.labelTextColor = .darkGray
    yAxis.axisLineColor = .darkGray
    yAxis.gridLineWidth.round()
    yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    

    let xAxis = lineChart.xAxis
    xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    xAxis.labelFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    xAxis.setLabelCount(5, force: false)
    xAxis.labelTextColor = .darkGray
    xAxis.axisLineColor = .darkGray
    lineChart.leftAxis.axisLineDashPhase = .nan
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this feature is not supported yet, so I would suggest to:
either enhance that library or do it by yourself:

- Subclass `XAxisRenderer` and `YAxisRenderer`
- In that subclasses, overwrite `drawLabels`, call the base function, and add the dots graphic (check the original `drawLabels` implementation).
- Create the subclass renderer instances and set it as `leftYAxisRenderer` / `rightYAxisRenderer` / `xAxisRenderer` in your chart.